Transfering colored balls from random bags into identical ones
Let's consider the following scenario:
There are $n$ colors, and there are $n^2$ colored balls, where we have $n$ balls of each of the $n$ colors. There are also $n$ bags $[b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n]$ where each bag contains $n$ of the above colored balls. Note that there is no condition here as to how these $n^2$ balls are distributed among the bags
Is it possible to transfer all of the balls into a new set of bags $[b'_1, b'_2, \dots, b'_n]$, where we

transfer one and only one ball from each bag $b_i$ to bag $b'_j$ for all $1\leq i,j \leq n$, AND

Each bag $b'_j$ contains one and only one ball of each of the $n$ colors.


If it is not possible for all the number of ways the colored balls can be present inside the initial bags, what additional conditions are needed to make sure such a transfer is possible?

Example
Lets consider $n=4$, with colors $R, G,B,Y$, and initial bags as:

$b_1=\{R,R,B,Y\}$
$b_2=\{G,G,Y,Y\}$
$b_3=\{B,B,B,Y\}$
$b_4=\{R,R,G,G\}$

Then a transfer can look like the below matrix $T$, where the color in $i^{th}$ row and $j^{th}$ column represnt the ball which went from $b_i$ to $b'_j$
$T=\begin{bmatrix} 
R & B & R & Y \\
Y & G & Y & G \\
B & Y & B & B \\
G & R & G & R
\end{bmatrix}$

I got to this subproblem while thinking the solution for another problem here
My first thought was to simply "construct" the transfer via a simple greedy approach, but I gave up after playing with it for a bit.
Another idea I have is to model the above problem as a max flow problem in graphs, which might give the correct insights to how to solve it further, but I can't correctly model it. Putting my current idea here, though I am sure it won't help much: I am constructing a graph $G$ with $2 + 2n^2$ nodes:

The first node is the source node which has $n^2$ or infite amount of in flow
Next $n^2$ nodes denote the colored balls before the transfer, and each node here has an inward edge with a flow limit of $1$ from the source.
Next $n^2$ nodes denote the colored balls after the transfer, I am facing problem here as to how to model the incoming edges from the previous $n^2$ nodes.

We can just add an edge for all pair of balls which have the same color here, but that won't enforce the only one ball from a bag to another constaint
To enforce the constraint of only one ball going from one bag to another, we can two dummy nodes for each pair of bags. Here all balls of a bag before the transfer has a directed edge to the first dummy node, which then has a directed edge to the 2nd (with flow limit 1), and lastly this 2nd dummy nide has directed edges to all balls of a bag after the transfer. But in this process, we lose the color aspect of the problem entirely.


The last node is the target node which has inward edges with a flow limit of $1$ coming from the above $n^2$ nodes. If this node reaches a max flow of $n^2$, a transfer is possible.

Any help is appreciated

This is a really neat question! First thoughts that come to mind for me are matrices or a collection of $n$ tuples $\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ with sum $(n,...,n)$. Though I'll think on this.

Thanks to @Steve D 's answer here, I have a construction now:
To construct it, we make a directed graph $G_1 =(V,E_1)$ where
$$\begin{split}
V =& \{S\}\\
&\cup \{\nu_{b_1}, \nu_{b_2}, \dots, \nu_{b_n} \}\\
&\cup \{\nu_{c_1}, \nu_{c_2}, \dots, \nu_{c_n} \}\\
&\cup \{T\}
\end{split}$$
$$\begin{split}
E_1 =& \{(S, \nu_{b_1}), (S, \nu_{b_2}),\dots,(S, \nu_{b_n})\}\\
&\cup \left\{\left(\nu_{b_i}, \nu_{c_j}\right)| \forall c_j \in b_i\right\}\\
&\cup \{(\nu_{c_1}, T), (\nu_{c_2}, T),\dots,(\nu_{c_n}, T)\}
\end{split}$$
We can use any network flow algorithm (like edmond karp) in this graph $G_1$ to find the max flow which will be $n$ (proof below). Using this flow, specifically the $(\nu_{b_i}, \nu_{c_j})$ edges which are filled in the flow, we remove the balls of color $c_j$ from bags $b_i$ to put in bag $b'_1$.
For bag $b'_2$ (and so on), we can update the graph $G_2 = (V, E_2)$ with the same formulation, but the edges like $(\nu_{b_i}, \nu_{c_j})$ will be created via the updated bags, i.e., after removing the colored balls from the previous steps.
Proof that the max flow will be $n$ for all $G_k$
For graph $G_k$, we consider the bipartite graph $BG_k = (X, Y, BE_k)$ where $$ X = \{\nu_{b_1}, \nu_{b_2}, \dots, \nu_{b_n} \}\\
Y = \{\nu_{c_1}, \nu_{c_2}, \dots, \nu_{c_n} \}\\
BE_k = \left\{\left(\nu_{b_i}, \nu_{c_j}\right)| \forall c_j \in b_i\right\}$$
Then $G_k$ has a max flow of $n$ if and only if $BG_k$ satisfies the Hall's marriage condition which is for any subset $W \subseteq X$, $|W| \leq |N_G(W)|$. We will prove this condition now.
The number of balls contained in any bag $b_i$ during this step is $n-k+1$, as $k-1$ balls have been removed in the previous steps corresponding to $G_1, G_2, \dots G_{k-1}$. Then the total number of balls contained in all bags $b_i \in W$ is $|W|(n-k+1)$.
Also for each color $c_j$, the total number of balls remaining in all bags of this color is $n-k+1$ with the same logic as above. Then by the pigeonhole principle, $\left|\left\{c_j \:|\:\forall c_j\in b_i \;  \forall b_i \in W \right\}\right| \geq \frac{|W|(n-k+1)}{n-k+1}$ or $|N_G(W)| \geq |W|$
